# Stringifying a linked list

Tags: python, class, while-loop, linked-list

Started to learn linked list today

This is more of a loop/class question than a linked list question:

The code that gives the right output:

```
 def stringify_list(self):
    string_list = ""
    current_node = self.get_head_node()
    while current_node:
      if current_node.get_value() != None:
        string_list += str(current_node.get_value()) + "\n"
      current_node = current_node.get_next_node()
    return string_list
```

The code that I thought of:

```
 def stringify_list(self):
    string_list = ""
    current_node = self.get_head_node()
    
    while current_node.get_value() != None:
      string_list += str(current_node.get_value()) + "\n"
      current_node = current_node.get_next_node()
      return string_list
```

My answer is just giving me only one output whereas the answer gives me four output. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It is strange that you treat a node value of `None` differently than another value. Why is that? There is no reason why a node couldn't have the value `None` and be a valid node in the list...

Answer (score 1):

You have a `return` call within the `while` loop so the code in the `while` is only ran once and the `string_list` is returned:

```
    while current_node.get_value() != None:
      string_list += str(current_node.get_value()) + "\n"
      current_node = current_node.get_next_node()
      return string_list # this line
```

You'd probably want to move that line outside of the while loop so that the loop will run to exhaustion:

```
    while current_node.get_value() != None:
      string_list += str(current_node.get_value()) + "\n"
      current_node = current_node.get_next_node()
    return string_list
```

Comment: Now I am getting an attribute error...
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_value'

Comment: I assume that's why the original code was `while current_node:`. `while current_node:` will ensure the next line doesn't get run if `current_node` is `None`.